# Creating a 'histogram' from a occurrence list

Tags: python, histogram

Python noob here in need of some help.

I have a set of data that is in the format `[['item', count], ........]` and a need to create a histogram of sort that prints an asterisk for every ten occurrences counted.

Example:

```
list=[['a', 22], ['b', 11], ['c', 45]]
```

Histogram:

```
a **
b *
c ****
```

Any ideas would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [['a', 22], ['b', 11], ['c', 45]]
for item in data:
    print(item[0] + ': ' + ('*' * (item[1] // 10)))
```

You can print a string multiple times with the `*` operator. So `'*' * 5` produces `*****`. I would use a dictionary instead of a list though:

```
data = {'a': 22, 'b':11, 'c':45}
for item in data:
    print(item + ': ' + ('*' * (data[item] // 10)))
```

just because a dictionary suits your purpose better.

Comment: And what if I'm only wanting one asterisk for every 10 counts?

Comment: I updated it. The `// 10` part truncates so the above code does indeed show one asterisk per 10 counts. 45 // 10 = 4 (trancate beens to ignore the decimal part).